# Rails - include module into controller, to be used in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, module

I'm really new to Rails and I try to setup a module file to be used in the view. So I believe the correct behavior is to define the module as a helper within a controller and voila, it should be working. However, that's not the case for me. Here is the structure.

```
lib
  functions
    -- form_manager.rb
```

form_manager.rb:

```
Module Functions 
  Module FormManager
    def error_message() ...
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   helper FormManager

   def new ...
```

Well, the structure is like the above and when I call the error_message from `new.html.erb` it gives me the error: `uninitialized constant UsersController::FormManager`.

So, first of all, I know that in rails 3 lib is not automatically loaded. Assuming that it is not mandatory to autoload the lib folder, how can I make this work and what am I missing?

BTW, please don't say that this question is duplicate. I'm telling you I've been searching for this crap for almost 2 days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your module is not autoloaded (at least not in 3.2.6). You have to load it explicitly. You can achieve this with the following line of code

```
 # in application.rb
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

You can check your autoload paths with `Rails.application.config.autoload_paths`. Maybe it's indeed defined for you?

Now you're sure your module gets loaded, you can check it in `rails console` by calling

```
> Functions::FormHelper
```

Now you can't use that module as a view helper by default. Use `#included` to define the helper when your module gets included. You achieve "lazy evaluation" this way. I think the problem with your code is that the `helper` method gets called before the module gets included. (somebody should correct me if I'm wrong)

Here's the code:

```
Module Functions 
  Module FormManager
    def error_message() ...
    end

    def self.included m
      return unless m < ActionController::Base
      m.helper_method :error_message
    end

  end
end
```

You should also remove the `helper` line from your controller.

EDIT:

You can achieve this without autoloading. Just use `require "functions/form_manager"`. You define a helper_method for every method. If you wish use all the module methods as helpers use

```
def self.included m
  return unless m < ActionController::Base
  m.helper_method self.instance_methods
end
```

EDIT2:

It appears that you don't need to use `self.included`. This achieves the same functionality:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  include Functions::FormManager
  helper_method Functions::FormManager.instance_methods

end
```

Comment: This has worked, thanks a lot! :) However, if I remove the helper it does not work, so better leave it as it is :) BTW, isn't there any other method except autoloading? Because I believe that when you autoload then even if you are not using the module it will be loaded anyway. And a second question: should I list every method in the module as you did in the included method? (I mean, like m.helper_method :create_form, m.helper_method :destroy_form etc...)

Comment: Hm, doesn't work without `helper`? Weird. Updated the post with the answers. You should have asked the question earlier, I'm sorry you've wasted 2 days on this :(

Comment: Doesn't work without autoload as well. I guess I'll have to stick with the autoload. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually it does. Use "require" instead of "include" when autoload is off.

Comment: well i've said that you should use `require` :)

Comment: You are better to use 'config.eager_load_paths' instead of 'config.autoload_paths'.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are namespacing `FormManager` inside of `Functions` which means you would call it by `helper Functions::FormManager`

Try that